# This was off-topic ..?

Tags: support, status-completed

My question about hwclock equivalent was off-topic? Why is that?

[hwclock equivalent in Windows server](https://serverfault.com/questions/458576/hwclock-equivalent-in-windows-server)

Comment: I... don't know... I can only assume because it was seen as a "give me a list of programs so that I don't have to google it myself" question... a quick edit should be able to fix that.

Comment: Looks like as I was writing that the question has been re-opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the question was reopened!